# insert element in a balanced search tree

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I have written the code below for inserting an element in a BST. It compiles without an error, but when I try to run it, I get segmentation error.

I tried to rewrite the function with only a node and an int instead of 2 nodes, but still I get segmentation error.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int key_value;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  struct node *parent;
  struct node *root;
};

void treeinsert( struct node *tree, struct node *z ) {
  struct node *y = NULL;
  struct node *x = tree->root;

  while( x!=NULL ) {
    y=x;
    if( z->key_value < x->key_value ) {
      x=x->left;
    } else {
      x=x->right;
    }
  }
  z->parent = y;
  if( y==NULL ) {
    tree->root = z;
  } else if(z->key_value < y->key_value) {
    y->left = z;
  } else {
    y->right = z;
  }

}

int main() {

  struct node *tree = 0;
  struct node *z = NULL;

  int s[5] = {4,2,7,1,9}, i;


  for( i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    z->key_value = s[i];
    treeinsert(tree, z);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Anyone has any idea why the segmentation error and how should I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

An idea is that you don't allocate `z` before using it in the main function and declare it as NULL